# How to run shell script in Ant while doing search and replace?

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

I am trying to achieve following with Ant.
I have a property file where we have list of tokens and their values.
This file is passed to Ant and it works great and does all the normal string replacement.

```
            <copy todir="${target_direcotry}" overwrite="true">
                    <fileset dir="config">
                            <include name="*.change_me"/>
                    </fileset>
                    <filterset begintoken="&lt;" endtoken="&gt;">
                            <filtersfile file="${property_file}"/>
                    </filterset>
                    <mapper type="glob" from="*.change_me" to="*"/>
            </copy>
```

Now If i have one of the token-value pair as follows :
**TOKEN_VALUE1=`./run_me.ksh`** in property file.

Target file test.xml.change_me has content :
You have `<TOKEN_VALUE1>` entries present !!!

With above code in build.xml and this new token in property file i am getting content of test.xml after running ant is :
You have `./run_me.ksh` entries present !!!

Output of script run_me.ksh will decide the value this token and give me output as follows :

### Scenario 1 :

Run_me.ksh output: 10

Required content of file test.xml after execution :
"You have 10 entries present !!!"

### Scenario 1 :

Run_me.ksh output: 20

Required content of file test.xml after execution :
"You have 20 entries present !!!"

Can i achieve this with Ant function/commands to run such shell script during replacements and how ?

Answer (score 0):

It is technically possible to achieve this with Ant using [FilterChain and FilterReader](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html) (specifically this one: [ScriptFilter](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html#scriptfilter)). However this is not so trivial and may have some portability issues. You may consider either writing your own task (or a specific FilterReader), or simply define a target that executes your shell script and store its result in a property and the use that property as value for token replacement.

Hereafter a snippet of how to launch a script in your token replacement task :

```
<copy todir="${target.dir}" overwrite="true">
    <fileset dir="${config.dir}">
        <include name="*.change_me" />
    </fileset>
    <filterchain>
        <!-- replace token with value in the property file (i.e. `run_me.sh`) -->
        <filterreader classname="org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens">
            <param type="propertiesfile" value="${token.properties}" />
        </filterreader>
        <tokenfilter>
            <!-- split result along a specific pattern ('`' character for instance). -->
            <stringtokenizer delims="`" delimsaretokens="false" />
            <!-- apply a script filter to execute shell if token is script name -->
            <scriptfilter language="javascript">
                <![CDATA[
                if( self.getToken().indexOf(".sh") != -1 ){
                    <!-- rely on ant Exec task to run script -->
                    exectask = project.createTask("exec");
                    exectask.setExecutable("sh");
                    exectask.createArg().setValue(self.getToken());
                    <!-- store output in an ant property : -->
                    exectask.setOutputproperty("result");
                    exectask.perform();
                    <!-- retrieve the ant property and use it to replace current token -->
                    self.setToken(project.getProperty("result"));
                }
                ]]>
            </scriptfilter>
        </tokenfilter>
    </filterchain>
    <mapper type="glob" from="*.change_me" to="*" />
</copy>
```